# MySQL join multiple rows from one table while selecting only a single row from the others

Tags: mysql

Maybe a bit of a strange title description, but i basically want to achieve something the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function does, only then keep the double entries.

I have four tables i want to join, `client`, `doctor`, `physio` and `records`

Depending on the variable `$client` i want to get the client details, attending doctor and therapist (one single row from three tables) and join *all* records for that user.

Say that in this case the `$client = 1`. The `records` table has five records where the column `r_client_id = 1`. If i run a query like below i only get one record from the `records` table, namely the first occurrence where `r_client_id = 1` (which makes sense of course):

```
SELECT
    client.c_id, client.c_name
    doctor.d_name, 
    physio.p_name, 
    records.r_record
FROM
    adm_clients AS client

    INNER JOIN 
        norm_client_doctor AS ncd ON ncd.ncd_client_id = client.c_id
    INNER JOIN 
        adm_doctor AS doctor ON doctor.d_id = ncd.ncd_doctor_id
    INNER JOIN 
        norm_client_physio AS ncp ON ncp.ncp_client_id = client.c_id
    INNER JOIN 
        adm_physio AS physio ON physio.p_id = ncp.ncp_physio_id

        LEFT JOIN 
            adm_doctor_records AS records ON records.r_client_id = client.c_id
WHERE
    client.c_id = '".$client."'
```

Now assume the five records where `r_client_id = 1` are like so:

```
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| r_id | r_client_id | r_record          | r_date   |
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| 1    | 1           | regular visit     | 10/10/12 |
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| 3    | 1           | emergency control | 24/10/12 |
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| 7    | 1           | regular visit     | 08/09/12 |
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| 18   | 1           | delivery          | 03/01/12 |
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| 20   | 1           | health checkup    | 10/12/11 |
+------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
```

I want my output to be in an array like so:

```
Client 1
 - Name Doctor
 - Name Physio

Records
 - Emergency control, 24/10/12
 - Regular visit, 10/10/12
 - Regular visit, 08/09/12
 - Delivery, 03/01/12
 - Health checkup, 10/12/11
```

The closest one i can image is a to add a `GROUP_CONCAT()` on the records, but that, of course, groups the 'regular visit', so i'll get 4 rows instead of 5

```
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT records.r_record SEPARATOR '|')
[..]
    echo(str_replace("|","<br>",$show->r_record));
```

Anybody an idea how to display *all* the matching records? I have the feeling i'm close, but i'm out of options by now..

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that when i remove the `DISTINCT`, it displays all the records twice..

**SOLVED:**

Got it working like so:

```
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CONCAT (records.r_date, '~', records.r_record, '~', records.r_paraph)
    SEPARATOR '|') AS clientDoctorRecords,
```

Comment: So why not group by client_id rather than record? Also you can use individual group concats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    client.c_id, client.c_name
    doctor.d_name, 
    physio.p_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(records.r_record)
FROM
    adm_clients AS client

    INNER JOIN 
        norm_client_doctor AS ncd ON ncd.ncd_client_id = client.c_id
    INNER JOIN 
        adm_doctor AS doctor ON doctor.d_id = ncd.ncd_doctor_id
    INNER JOIN 
        norm_client_physio AS ncp ON ncp.ncp_client_id = client.c_id
    INNER JOIN 
        adm_physio AS physio ON physio.p_id = ncp.ncp_physio_id

        LEFT JOIN 
            adm_doctor_records AS records ON records.r_client_id = client.c_id
WHERE
    client.c_id = '".$client."'
GROUP BY
    client.c_id
```

If you want `r_date` to come along with `record` in one column, then you can use plain `CONCAT` first and then do a `GROUP_CONCAT` on it.